# How to active a hidden button if a other button pass the validation i have on my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hello i'm coding a multi step form and need a litle help .

So i have a jquery script that divide my forms based on the  `<fieldset></fieldset>` tag

My question is how to make it so that if i click over my submit button and all of my labels are filled as they should or to say they pass  my validation  to active a hidden button i have inside the script ?
My submit button code

```
<button type="submit" class="button" >Submit</button>
```

My next button code that need to be hidden and be active from my submit button if all the questions are right filled and be inactive if not.

```
<input type="button" name="Next" class="next action-button" style="display:none" id='button1' value="Próximo" />
```

A little weird i know but i need it so , thanks in advance

My validation

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function()
            {
                // Validation
                $("#sky-form").validate(
                {                   
                    // Rules for form validation
                    rules:
                    {
                        name:
                        {
                            required: true
                        },
                        surname:
                        {
                            required: true
                        },
                        email:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                        phone:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 4
                        },
                        url:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            url: true
                        },
                        captcha:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            remote: 'captcha/process.php'
                        }
                    },

                    // Messages for form validation
                    messages:
                    {
                        name:
                        {
                            required: 'Please enter your name',
                        },
                        surname:
                        {
                            required: 'Please enter your name',
                        },
                        email:
                        {
                            required: 'Please enter your email address',
                            email: 'Please enter a VALID email address'
                        },
                        phone:
                        {
                            required: 'Please enter your message'
                        },
                        url:
                        {
                            required: 'Please enter your URL'
                        },
                        captcha:
                        {
                            required: 'Please enter characters',
                            remote: 'Correct captcha is required'
                        }
                    },
                    // Do not change code below
                errorPlacement: function(error, element)
                    {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    }
                });
            }); 
        </script>
```

To link the buttons we can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#button1').click(function(){ $('#button2').click() });</script>
```

by giving both id .

Comment: Needing to validate part of a form before button is available isn't uncommon. Just not clear what your issue is without seeing how your validation works

Comment: just posted my validation , thank you for your post

Comment: can loop through all the `:input` selector in current fieldset and keep track of `$(this).valid()` which returns boolean. Is a method of the validation plugin that can be used on elements or form itself

Comment: can you please write the code that would do that or just a example since i'm not good at jquery :S

Comment: by the way i know how to link them but i need the hidden button to be inactive until all fields are filled right , i can link them with this code by giving them id for example "<script type="text/javascript">$('#button1').click(function(){ $('#button2').click() });</script> "

Comment: perhaps yuo should look into a  form wizard plugin that has integrated validation

Comment: no i'm not interested on them i want to design my form as i want and not look identical with others forms but thank you for your suggestion